# SailsJS i18n module not changing lang file even the locale was changed

Tags: internationalization, sails.js

I debugging a SailsJS app, if I print the sails global variables it has the right values for locales, and defaultLocale, etc...

I changing the locale with Accept-Language header in PostMan and works like a charm.

Even it has the right locales, i18n module is taking always the default language translation file. Does someone know what could be happening?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it was due my local environment locales config(Ubuntu 18.10), given when I deployed to the VPS it worked like a charm.

Thanks anyway ;)